# ERROR: [object Object] on resolve(key-value pairs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I have a function, where I want to return (resolve- upon promise completion) a set of key-value pairs, which I cannot.

```
const getCartSummary = async(order) => {
    return new Promise(async(request, resolve) => {
        try {
            const cart = order.cart;
            console.log(order.coupon_applied);
            console.log(order.shipping_cost);
            console.log(order.net_total);
            console.log((order.shipping_cost + order.net_total));
            console.log(cart);
            resolve({
                coupon_applied: order.coupon_applied,
                shipping_cost: order.shipping_cost,
                cart_subtotal: order.net_total,
                cart_total: (order.shipping_cost + order.net_total),
                cart: cart
            });
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Here, I can see the values of all each individual value and can return successfully. But in the function whenever I try and access / use these values I get an `ERROR: [object Object]`. I am not being able to understand why.

When I am calling the function via a statement-

```
const cart_summary = await getCartSummary(order);
console.log(cart_summary)
```

I am getting the following output in my terminal-

```
false
200
15760
15960
[ { qty: 4,
    _id: 60684c03dc527b8f08628ab0,
    product:
     { info: [Object],
       quantity: 5,
       _id: 6062010293f67c50a808e031,
       name:
        'Twelve Blends- Spice Box With 12 Containers & Spoon In Sheesham Wood',
       price: 1890,
       vendor: 'Spice Club',
       __v: 0 } },
  { qty: 5,
    _id: 606c0b4561f7ef3dde3c35a9,
    product:
     { info: [Object],
       quantity: 1,
       _id: 6062010293f67c50a808e032,
       name:
        'Thirteen Blends- Spice Box With 12 Containers & Spoon In Sheesham Wood',
       price: 1600,
       vendor: 'Spice Club',
       __v: 0 } } ]
ERROR: [object Object]
```

Comment: getCartSummary function defination should need to have 2 parameters user and order

Comment: Nah, it's just 1 param. Mistake edited in stack-overflow. Problem persists

Comment: Can u send the console err msg in catch block?

Comment: [object Object] is the Error message

Comment: I think that is error obj, u need to console as err.msg

Comment: Nahh, So when the promise was rejected, I am later printing the message via ```console.log(chalk.red(`ERROR: ${e}`));```. That comes out to be ```ERROR: [object Object]```

Comment: ${e.msg} or e.message can u try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create your promise wrong:

```js
const getCartSummary = async(order) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const cart = order.cart;
            console.log(order.coupon_applied);
            console.log(order.shipping_cost);
            console.log(order.net_total);
            console.log((order.shipping_cost + order.net_total));
            console.log(cart);
            resolve({
                coupon_applied: order.coupon_applied,
                shipping_cost: order.shipping_cost,
                cart_subtotal: order.net_total,
                cart_total: (order.shipping_cost + order.net_total),
                cart: cart
            });
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}
```

You actually called the `resolve` function `request` and the `reject` function was your `resolve` function. So when you resolved the promise with the order information you actually rejected it. Also the function you pass into the Promise constructor shouldn't be async.